# tf.logging.__dict__[hparams.verbosity] / 10) KeyError: 'INFO'

Tags: tensorflow

Trying to run GitHub codes of nonlocal recurrent networks.
I am ending up getting this error. How to debug this error?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trainer.py", line 97, in 
    tf.logging.**dict**[hparams.verbosity] / 10)
KeyError: 'INFO'

tried editing codes. but not working.

Answer (score 0):

On tensorflow version 1.14, below code will cause the error.

```
tf.logging.dict[hparams.verbosity]
```

So you can fix the code like below. It will be ok on tf 1.14.

```
getattr(tf.logging, hparams.verbosity)
```